# Use access token from Rest API to access Metadata?

Tags: metadata

Can we retrieve Metadata like apex classes, VF pages, WF rules rtc... from different org via rest api while I have the access token to that Org?

Or else there are any other way to access those details when I have the Access Token?

BR,
Mudi

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, yes. Session ID values and Access Tokens are generally mutually exchangeable. The Access Token must have the "api" scope or the "full" scope in order to use APIs, and the user you're logged in as must also have the relevant permissions (e.g. Customize Application) if you intend to modify metadata. You can read more about scopes and so on in ["Digging Deeper into OAuth 2.0 on Force.com"](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com) and related resources linked at the bottom of the page. The REST API also includes read-only metadata details for objects, fields, classes, pages, and record types without needing to directly call the Metadata API. The [workbench](http://workbench.developerforce.com) also uses OAuth access tokens, which would only be possible if the Metadata API could be used with the Access Token from OAuth, which it is. If you're having a specific problem, please feel free to ask questions with specific error messages.